# Crop PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, crop

How can I crop a PDF using iTextsharp in C#?? How do I modify the CropBoxSize parameters to create a new cropped pdf file?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to use it actually. My requirements were very simple. So I just altered the parameters of the Rectangle function of the PDF and generated a new PDF. Thank you so much for the project!

Answer (score 2):

you can take a look at my project http://pdfebookcutter.codeplex.com/

Comment: Great project !  
Too bad that you disabled rating, it is worth 5 stars.

Comment: Uses new iTextSharp version 5.0+ -- boo hiss